# p:dataTable filteredValue always null

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

i have the following code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:dataTable 
            var="report" 
            value="#{businessDomain.value.reportEntities}" 
            style="padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;"
            filteredValue="#{businessDomain.value.filteredReportEntities}" 
            scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200" paginator="false" rows="999"
            rowKey="#{report.id}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" selection="#{reportController.entity}" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{reportController.onRowSelect}" update="@(form)"/>
        <p:column name="name" filterBy="#{report.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <tp:outputText object="#{report}"/>
            <h:outputText value=" (#{myWithFailedStatusI18nCategoryModel.i18nCodeMap[report.status]})" rendered="#{report.status != 'A'}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column name="button" style="width:20px;">
            <p:commandButton update="@(form)" action="#{controller.getPathToDetailForm}"
                    icon="ui-icon-wrench" styleClass="tpTableButton"
                    rendered="#{reportController.isEntityUpdateable and  organizationController.authenticatedUserOrganization.id == report.organization.id}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{reportController.entity}" value="#{report}"/>    
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

in the controller for this view i have the class (which is behind the value businessDomain.value) :

```
public class ReportCategory{
   ...
   private List<ReportEntity> reportEntities;
   private List<ReportEntity> filteredReportEntities;
   ...

   public List<ReportEntity> getReportEntities() {
       return reportEntities;
   }

   public List<ReportEntity> getFilteredReportEntities() {
      getLogger().info("getFilter called")
      return filteredReportEntities;
   }

   public void setFilteredReportEntities(List<ReportEntity> filteredReportEntities) {
      getLogger().info("setFilter called: "+filteredReportEntities);
      this.filteredReportEntities = filteredReportEntities;
   }
}
```

initial without filtering everything is fine.. the entities are getting displayed the right way. But if i type something in the filter i get an getFilter and setFilter call.. where the setFilter parameter value is always null:

```
getFilter called
setFilter called: null
```

I was following the primefaces example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

(I am using primefaces 5.3.14)
I found this question but i does not help me a lot cause im
[filterValue for a dataTable in Primefaces 5.3 always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626608/filtervalue-for-a-datatable-in-primefaces-5-3-always-null)

Comment: Did you try with last vesion of PF (e.g today is 6.2)? 5.3 is pretty old

Comment: start dropping `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @Rapster i cant update so easy.. thats the reason - so no i did not checked with the last version of PF.

Comment: You left out the scope of "businessDomain".  If its @RequestScoped then that explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: My best bet would be to debug `FilterFeature#filter` method, from there you'll see what's wrong. This is a good way to start to undertand your problem

Comment: @Melloware its session scoped.
[at]Rapster thanks i will test it - hope i will find the issue